# HttpWebRequest does not include "Pragma: no-cache" header when doing a POST

Tags: .net, debugging, httpwebrequest

I'm using an HttpWebRequest that has a CachePolicy of *HttpRequestCacheLevel.Reload*. When doing a GET the "Pragma: no-cache" header is in the request (as tracked through Fiddler). But when doing the exact same request using a POST then the "Pragma: no-cache" header is not included.

Is there a reason for this? Is it a bug? And is there a workaround?

Thanks.

EDIT: Just to be clearer about my goal. I want to have my POST request made using HttpWebRequest to include the "Pragma: no-cache" header, regardless of whether it is required or not. I thought setting the HttpWebRequest.CachePolicy to Reload alone would accomplish this. The reason I need this is because the site I'm making the request against does some checks for this header and is expecting it.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP **does** allow caching of the response to a POST request.  From [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), section 9.5;

> Responses to this method are not cacheable, unless the response
>      includes appropriate Cache-Control or Expires header fields. However,
>      the 303 (See Other) response can be used to direct the user agent to
>      retrieve a cacheable resource.

This means that if a POST response includes Cache-Control or Expires (or, given a strict reading of section 13, even a validator like Last-Modified or ETag), the response can be used to satisfy future GET requests. [1](http://www.mnot.net/javascript/xmlhttprequest/cache.html)

Since the POST is not sending a *no-cache*, the default is the response won't be cached.  It only needs to send a cache policy if you want the response of the post to be cacheable.